# Merge Sort(just the merge) will not successfully merge the last part of the array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, mergesort

I am writing a program that performs counting sort in parallel for a single array of random integers. Once this is completed and all threads are done, I must merge the now sorted sections of the array into a fully sorted array.

for example: {1,3,9,12,2,4,7,8} into {1,2,3,4,7,8,9,12}

my sort works, and the output is like so after trying to merge using two threads to sort(which works) but i want to be able to use more than two:

```
Sorted Array:   1 1 1 4 5 6 6 6 8 9 1 1 3 4 5 5 5 5 8 9 
Merged Final:   1 1 1 1 1 3 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 8 9 9
```

This is using two threads, I cannot figure out how to implement my merge section to accommodate more than 2 threads. I know I can manipulate it to allow for it, but I can't seem to get it right. Here is what I get when I try with three threads sorting an array of length 21 and each thread sorts a subsection of length 7. Here I can't get it to merge the last 7 characters. Each subsection is sorted properly.

```
Unsorted Array: 75 43 20 65 36 25 78 64 5 1 90 8 59 3 88 69 47 11 91 26 0 

Sorted Array:   1 3 5 8 20 25 36 43 59 64 65 75 78 90 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Here is my merge part of the code:

```
        //merging the subsections into final sorted array
        int[] temp = new int[data.length]; //temp array, data would not work if i tried to overwrite it
        int i = 0;//increment for one subsection
        int j = i + subLength;//increment for another subsection
        int x = 0;//increment for location in temp array

        while (i < subLength && j < subLength*2) {
            if (data[i] < data[j]) {
                temp[x] = data[i];
                i++;
            } else {
                temp[x] = data[j];
                j++;
            }
            x++;
        }
        while( i < subLength){ //getting remaining values from arrays
            temp[x++] = data[i++];
        }
        while( j < subLength*2){//getting remaining values from arrays
            temp[x++] = data[j++];
        }
        //putting temp array back into data array
        for (lcv = 0; lcv < data.length ; lcv++) {
            data[lcv] = temp[lcv];
        }
```

Comment: It's only going to merge 2 parts of your array not 3. i.e. array indices 0..6 and 7..13, whilst indices 14 .. 20 aren't merged if `subLength` is 7. You will need to repeatedly merge, i.e. merge sublist 3 with the result of the first merge.

Comment: Yeah, I understand the logic behind what I need to make it do, results of first merge with 3, results of second merge with 4 and so on. I cant get the code to work with the ideas I have tried.